# How to fix the video loading from youtube in owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, owl-carousel

I have video to be loaded in my web page,it has to be played when the web page is opened but it takes time for me to load and then it is playing i want to reduce this time completely..is there any plugin available..? please help me with some solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Load video by iframe, It will not block the page load,

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Use above code the video will auto play.

[Refer this](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/) URL explained detailed,

Comment: Thanx @ GNANA ,the above code  wont take time to load? Because in my web page it takes so much time to load the video, so i wanna reduce the time , it should not be shown as it is taking time, otherwise is there any possibility of reducing the resolutions, bandwidth etc?

Comment: If you use iframe for load video thats not affect your time to load. So its work for you